# Microsoft Excel wants to use my Confidential Information

Tags: microsoft-excel, keychain

I have MacOS Monterey version 12.6

I also have OneDrive

When I installed Excel app and opened it I get this prompt

[image]

I don't recall creating this type of password

I use the admin password to open my laptop, and my OneDrive password but it does not work

What is this keychain?

Comment: iCloud Keychain is Apple's password/authentication manager. Use the password you associated with that app to login.

Comment: I never created password. I only created admin password to log onto MacBook